# PHP GD creating graph from a MYSQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently creating a bar graph for PHP using GD (inb4 use Java-script, I can't. This is a requirement) As it stands I have a functioning Bar graph in GD that i can display normal numbers with but now I am trying to retrieve data from a MYSQL table and display it in the graph.

```
require "connect.php";
$sql = "SELECT 
title, searchcount
FROM movies
ORDER BY
searchcount DESC 
LIMIT 10";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $data = [
            $row['title'] => substr_count($row['searchcount'], "1"),
        ];
    }
}
```

This above code currently works in retrieving one of the required 10 results. What I can't figure out is how to retrieve the other 9, any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIiMt.jpg
This here is a link to the Graph at its current state

How the graph is drawn.

```
/*
 * Chart settings and create image
 */

// Image dimensions
$imageWidth = 700;
$imageHeight = 400;

// Grid dimensions and placement within image
$gridTop = 40;
$gridLeft = 50;
$gridBottom = 340;
$gridRight = 650;
$gridHeight = $gridBottom - $gridTop;
$gridWidth = $gridRight - $gridLeft;

// Bar and line width
$lineWidth = 1;
$barWidth = 20;

// Font settings
$font = 'OpenSans-Regular.ttf';
$fontSize = 10;

// Margin between label and axis
$labelMargin = 8;

// Max value on y-axis
$yMaxValue = 25;

// Distance between grid lines on y-axis
$yLabelSpan = 5;

// Init image
$chart = imagecreate($imageWidth, $imageHeight);

// Setup colors
$backgroundColor = imagecolorallocate($chart, 255, 255, 255);
$axisColor = imagecolorallocate($chart, 85, 85, 85);
$labelColor = $axisColor;
$gridColor = imagecolorallocate($chart, 212, 212, 212);
$barColor = imagecolorallocate($chart, 47, 133, 217);

imagefill($chart, 0, 0, $backgroundColor);

imagesetthickness($chart, $lineWidth);

/*
 * Print grid lines bottom up
 */

for($i = 0; $i <= $yMaxValue; $i += $yLabelSpan) {
    $y = $gridBottom - $i * $gridHeight / $yMaxValue;

    // draw the line
    imageline($chart, $gridLeft, $y, $gridRight, $y, $gridColor);

    // draw right aligned label
    $labelBox = imagettfbbox($fontSize, 0, $font, strval($i));
    $labelWidth = $labelBox[4] - $labelBox[0];

    $labelX = $gridLeft - $labelWidth - $labelMargin;
    $labelY = $y + $fontSize / 2;

    imagettftext($chart, $fontSize, 0, $labelX, $labelY, $labelColor, $font, strval($i));
}

/*
 * Draw x- and y-axis
 */

imageline($chart, $gridLeft, $gridTop, $gridLeft, $gridBottom, $axisColor);
imageline($chart, $gridLeft, $gridBottom, $gridRight, $gridBottom, $axisColor);

/*
 * Draw the bars with labels
 */

$barSpacing = $gridWidth / count($data);
$itemX = $gridLeft + $barSpacing / 2;

foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    // Draw the bar
    $x1 = $itemX - $barWidth / 2;
    $y1 = $gridBottom - $value / $yMaxValue * $gridHeight;
    $x2 = $itemX + $barWidth / 2;
    $y2 = $gridBottom - 1;

    imagefilledrectangle($chart, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $barColor);

    // Draw the label
    $labelBox = imagettfbbox($fontSize, 0, $font, $key);
    $labelWidth = $labelBox[4] - $labelBox[0];

    $labelX = $itemX - $labelWidth / 2;
    $labelY = $gridBottom + $labelMargin + $fontSize;

    imagettftext($chart, $fontSize, 0, $labelX, $labelY, $labelColor, $font, $key);

    $itemX += $barSpacing;
}

/*
 * Output image to browser
 */

imagepng($chart, 'chart.png');
```

Comment: Are your `title`s all the same? can you `var_dump($data)` after `while` loop?

Comment: No they aren't but its a dynamic database that needs to retrieve the title for the slot and order them via the searchcount

Comment: Show the result of `var_dump($data)` after `while` loop.

Comment: var_dump after the loop simply shows all the results as if i was to print an array. It doesn't put them into the graph

Comment: can you post that?

Comment: Here is a link https://imgur.com/FdZQlc8

Comment: There are only 9 elements in that `dump` (should be 10, or i do not see drawed set in this `dump`), also i have a question what `$row['searchcount']` represent like, show example. Also this is a not full code to be considered to resolve your issue, because you did not show how you draw you data.

Comment: In the `dump` file you can see that the `$value` of all 9 elements is equal to `0`.

Comment: Have you tried my changes?

Comment: Yes, that fixed it. Thank you Serghei

Comment: You are very welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i tested your code and it works, so my guess is that is not formatted the right way or you not getting the right output from DB.
Try to change this lines:

```
$data = [
            $row['title'] => substr_count($row['searchcount'], "1"),
        ];
```

to this:

```
$data[$row['title']] = substr_count($row['searchcount'], "1");
```

As you expecting to get a `$key => $value` pair, so the `$value` to not be an `array()`. Here are the `test` data i used and result:

```
<?php

$data = array(
    'test1' => 10,
    'test2' => 4,
    'test3' => 10,
    'test4' => 4,
    'test5' => 10,
    'test6' => 4,
    'test7' => 10,
    'test8' => 4,
    'test9' => 10,
    'test10' => 4
);


/*
 * Chart settings and create image
 */

// Image dimensions
$imageWidth = 700;
$imageHeight = 400;

// Grid dimensions and placement within image
$gridTop = 40;
$gridLeft = 50;
$gridBottom = 340;
$gridRight = 650;
$gridHeight = $gridBottom - $gridTop;
$gridWidth = $gridRight - $gridLeft;

// Bar and line width
$lineWidth = 1;
$barWidth = 20;

// Font settings
$font = getcwd() . '/arial.ttf'; // I switched to use Arial font 
$fontSize = 10;

// Margin between label and axis
$labelMargin = 8;

// Max value on y-axis
$yMaxValue = 25;

// Distance between grid lines on y-axis
$yLabelSpan = 5;

// Init image
$chart = imagecreate($imageWidth, $imageHeight);

// Setup colors
$backgroundColor = imagecolorallocate($chart, 255, 255, 255);
$axisColor = imagecolorallocate($chart, 85, 85, 85);
$labelColor = $axisColor;
$gridColor = imagecolorallocate($chart, 212, 212, 212);
$barColor = imagecolorallocate($chart, 47, 133, 217);

imagefill($chart, 0, 0, $backgroundColor);

imagesetthickness($chart, $lineWidth);

/*
 * Print grid lines bottom up
 */

for($i = 0; $i <= $yMaxValue; $i += $yLabelSpan) {
    $y = $gridBottom - $i * $gridHeight / $yMaxValue;

    // draw the line
    imageline($chart, $gridLeft, $y, $gridRight, $y, $gridColor);

    // draw right aligned label
    $labelBox = imagettfbbox($fontSize, 0, $font, strval($i));
    $labelWidth = $labelBox[4] - $labelBox[0];

    $labelX = $gridLeft - $labelWidth - $labelMargin;
    $labelY = $y + $fontSize / 2;

    imagettftext($chart, $fontSize, 0, $labelX, $labelY, $labelColor, $font, strval($i));
}

/*
 * Draw x- and y-axis
 */

imageline($chart, $gridLeft, $gridTop, $gridLeft, $gridBottom, $axisColor);
imageline($chart, $gridLeft, $gridBottom, $gridRight, $gridBottom, $axisColor);

/*
 * Draw the bars with labels
 */

$barSpacing = $gridWidth / count($data);
$itemX = $gridLeft + $barSpacing / 2;

foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    // Draw the bar
    $x1 = $itemX - $barWidth / 2;
    $y1 = $gridBottom - $value / $yMaxValue * $gridHeight;
    $x2 = $itemX + $barWidth / 2;
    $y2 = $gridBottom - 1;

    imagefilledrectangle($chart, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $barColor);

    // Draw the label
    $labelBox = imagettfbbox($fontSize, 0, $font, $key);
    $labelWidth = $labelBox[4] - $labelBox[0];

    $labelX = $itemX - $labelWidth / 2;
    $labelY = $gridBottom + $labelMargin + $fontSize;

    imagettftext($chart, $fontSize, 0, $labelX, $labelY, $labelColor, $font, $key);

    $itemX += $barSpacing;
}

/*
 * Output image to browser
 */

imagepng($chart, 'chart.png');


?>
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: That fixes the output of the title issue which i must thank you for, but I believe I was using substr_count incorrect to begin with as the searchcount is an int in the SQL database and not a string, so now I will have to try and fix that

Comment: You Bet:) I was thinking that someone store the value of `$row['searchcount']` like `1 1 1 ...` thats weird